# PhoneGap working networkstatus example for online-build

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

can someone show me a actually example for a simple app to show the network-status.
Build with PhoneGap online

Targetsystem: Android Tablet (4.2.2)

My old app is working in Chrome with the Ripple extension. Networkstatus and GPS works great.

But now the app doesn't alert the networkstatus.

```
 function checkConnection() {
 var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

 var states = {};
 states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
 states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
 states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
 states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
 states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
 states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
 states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

 alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
 }
```

I have checked the documentation, but i'm not sure about

```
 uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
```

in PhoneGap... and the documentation is not clear or sometimes not up2date.
So i killed some hours and it's really frustrating for me :-(

So, a simple example was great!
A index.html and the config.xml will be sufficient, or?

(i'm able to upload to github and build at build.phonegap.com...)

Thank you :)
Olli

Comment: Did you install the Network Status plugin? See: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_connection_connection.md.html

Comment: @Pataar: yes, in my config.xml `<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager" />
</feature>` - have try the permission-part in the config.xml and AndroidManifest.xml too, but can not see any difference.

Comment: Which version of Phonegap are you using?

Comment: I don't use the local environment. I just edit my html-file and push it to github and use https://build.phonegap.com

Comment: And I use the Ripple extension for Chrome-browser.

Comment: build.phonegap.com used PhoneGap v. 3.6.3

Comment: Okay with `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"/>` in the config.xml it works well!! :-)